# WordPress or Drupal for an online shop?

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I'm about to build a website that has a couple of static pages, a shop and (later) a newsletter system with some CRM-like functionality.

I've made a few sites with WordPress so I'm leaning towards it. It also has some promising shop plugins.

But while WordPress has a pretty good user interface for blogs and simple sites, I'm worried that it won't "scale", i.e. be as easy to use for the shop, newsletter and CRM features as I'd like it to be.

The elephant in my room is right now Drupal, would you say that it is better suited for what I want to do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_the_room

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has nice plugins for all the major newsletters and even a robust plugin to do your own news letter... (don't do that).The same goes for CRM in WordPress.

In Drupal, things are in flux with commerce. UberCart and Drupal 6 is a super-stable, mature system for commerce. However, D7 is the new standard for Drupal sites. Drupal Commerce is a promising module, but you'll need to check on the status of plugins for features you will need before you jump into it... speaking of jumping the best way to get into Drupal Commerce is with kickstart: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart

Also, if you've never used Drupal before expect a learning curve as you get up to speed on entity types, bundles, taxonomies, content types, nodes, templates, blocks, and views.

Comment: Would you say that I should use WordPress for one type of site and Drupal for another or should I eventually try to settle for a single system?